# Find the solution of the given initial value problem (differential equations)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question: $$\frac{dy}{dt}+ty=1+t$$ where $y(\frac{3}{2})=0$.

So I know this is a non-homogeneous equation and as I started working on it, I ended up with:

$$e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}y=\int_{\frac{3}{2}}^{t} e^{\frac{\tau^2}{2}}d\tau$$

and I'm stuck at this step. Any help?

Comment: It seems this equation does not have an elementary solution, the solution involves the error function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a first order linear differential equation of the form:

[image]

The general solution is given by:

[image]

where:

[image]

called the integrating factor.

In your question,

$p(x) =t$ and $q(x) =t+1$.

I guess you can solve it from here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear first order first degree ODE of the form y'+P(x)y=Q(x).
Here, P(x)=t and Q(x)=1-t.
Now you already found the correct integrating factor(I.F.) i.e. exp(t^2/2).

solution of this form of ode is given by : y*(I.F.)= ∫(I.F.)*Q(x) dx + c , c is a constant of integration

You can easily evaluate this integral without putting the limits of integration and then using the initial value you can find the value of c.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Frank Lu, this is a very complex differential equation. For $$\frac{dy}{dt}+ty=0$$ the solution is simple $$y=C e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$ and the variation of parameters leads to $$\frac{dC}{dt}=(1+t)e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$$ so $$C=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}+\int e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt+K$$ and the problem comes from the last integral since $$\int e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ where appears the imaginary error function $\frac{\text{erf(i t)}}{i}$. So, no solution in terms of  elementary functions.